# R - adding legend to plot where par(mfrow = c(2, 1))

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to add a legend to a plot which is the top plot of a two plot figure. However, the legend is getting massively stretched out so that nothing can be seen and it obscures the end of the plot. Here is the code to reproduce the problem:

```
cars = c(1, 3, 6, 4, 9)

par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar=c(5,5,2,2))
plot(cars)

legend("topright", legend=c("label1", "label2"))
```

And here is what it looks like:

[image: Problem legend]

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Do the arguments `cex = 0.5, horiz = TRUE` solve the problem? Also, I am not getting what you have in the posted image, my legend does have labels.

Comment: Ok, I think there might be something wrong with my RStudio - it is definitely returning the image above. But i just tried the same code with an online interpreter and the legend did show the labels.

Comment: In RStudio you can restart the R session. Maybe the problem will be gone.